# LocalStorage in NextJS , useEffect problem

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage, use-effect

I have a problem to get and set data in localStorage, i use NextJs then i can´t use localStorage initially.

I try to resolve  with a useEffect but I have a infinite loop, i know that it's for the dependency. I don´t know the best way to resolve the problem, with a useCallback or  useMemo or useRef.

I paste a part of the code with the problem.

```
      const [ meetings, setMeetings] = useState([]) // meetings= [{meeting1},{meeting2}]
      
      useEffect(() => {

       if(localStorage.getItem('meetings') === undefined || 
         localStorage.getItem('meetings') === '' ||
         localStorage.getItem('meetings') === null
         ){
          localStorage.setItem('meetings', JSON.stringify([]))         
         }


       if( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meetings')).length === 0){
            
             const meetingsInLocalStorage  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meetings'))
             setMeetings([...meetings, meetingsInLocalStorage])

       }
       },[meetings])
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to include `meetings` in the dependencies array?

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten this conditional to

```
localStorage.getItem('meetings') === undefined ||  localStorage.getItem('meetings') === '' || localStorage.getItem('meetings') === null
```

This

```
!localStorage.getItem('meetings')
```

---

This snippet of code doesn't make sense because, if the data from the localStorage is empty

```
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meetings')).length === 0) {
```

This will be empty as well

```
const meetingsInLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("meetings"));
```

And when you spread the meetings array, you don't spread the `meetingsInLocalStorage`, you keep pushing the empty array into the `meetings` state.

```
setMeetings([...meetings, meetingsInLocalStorage]);
```

Your data will look like `[ [], [], ...]`, and the meetings variable changes, so the `useEffect` runs again leading to the infinite loop.

#### Finally

---

I assume you want to update the meetings state if there were some in the `localStorage`

So your check should be

```
if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("meetings")).length > 0) {
  const meetingsInLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("meetings"));
  setMeetings([...meetings, ...meetingsInLocalStorage]);
}
```